# How to make QLabel's text "connected" with some variable, so the text will update once the variable's changed?

Tags: qt, qt5, qlabel

Consider following example:

```
int i = 0;

QLabel label("Number = " + QString::number(i));

label.show(); // label displays "Number = 0"

i = 5;

// label should display "Number = 5" now
```

How to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Make the variable property of an object (via Q_PROPERTY) and :

```
connect(object_ptr, &Object::variableChanged, [=](int i){
    label->setText("Number = " + QString::number(i));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

QLabel::setText() is a public slot. When the variable is modified, you have to call this setText() to display.
If you wish to monitor the change, you can start a QTimer, use QTimer::timeout() signal, wire up setText() slot.